# DuckDB - How to iterate over the result returned from duckdb.sql command

Tags: python, duckdb

Using DuckDB Python client, I want to iterate over the results returned from query like

```
import duckdb
employees = duckdb.sql("select * from 'employees.csv' ")
```

Using **type(employees)** returns 'duckdb.duckdb.DuckDBPyRelation'. I'm able to get the number of rows with **len(employees)**, however for-loop iteration seems to not work.

What is the correct way to process each row at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, from [DuckDB API](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html), something like the following should work. 
I unfortunately cannot test it because DuckDB's package won't install for whatever reason.
I hope this helps you get in the right path to finding your answer.

```
import duckdb

employees = duckdb.sql("select * from 'employees.csv'")
rows = employees.fetchall()

# Iterate over the rows
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Comment: The mentioned approach to fetchall rows as a list will be fine when number of rows are limited. Can you also describe how to use fetchmany for processing in batches

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for batching the rows:

```
import duckdb
batch_size = 10

handle = duckdb.sql("select * from 'employees.csv'")

while batch := handle.fetchmany(batch_size):
    print(batch)
```